# Можно ли в asp.net core вынести view в папку wwwroot?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

В проекте есть одна страница, на которой имеется блок с информацией, информация очень часто меняется, не хочется каждый раз заново публиковать проект.

Видел варианты с простой `html` страницей, но хотелось бы знать конкретно про `cshtml`.

Comment: А почему бы из контроллера не отдавать PartialView? Информацию можно читать из любого (JSON, TXT, CSV, etc.) файла в wwwroot (или другого ресурса) и добавлять её в возвращаемое представление.